# Error 404 when Rails welcome page tries to fetch rails.png in Nginx + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

### I'm using the following configuration:

- Ubuntu 12.04 desktop i386
- Ruby 1.9.3p327
- Rails 3.2.9
- NodeJS 0.8.14
- Nginx + Phusion Passenger

### I followed these steps:

1. Crate a new Ubuntu virtual machine to test with
2. Install Ruby + Rails + NodeJS
3. Install Passenger + Nginx from [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download)
4. Create a new Rails app in **/home/gerald/myapp** without ActiveRecord (to discard DB issues)
5. Run the said Rails app in dev mode (Rails server)

It worked perfectly, I was even able to see the rails.png image.

### The problem is...

...When I configured Nginx to run the said app, I got a **404 error in the rails.png** image.

These are the lines I added to **/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf** file:

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mydomain.com;
        root /home/gerald/myapp/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
    ...
}
```

The Nginx error.log only says:

```
2012/11/19 15:07:06 [error] 17398#0: *1 open() "/home/gerald/myapp/public/assets/rails.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/rails.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rails.png file is a asset, it's in asset pipeline, you should configure your nginx vhost.

It's something like:

```
location ~* ^/assets/ {
# Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
# http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

# Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
# Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
# reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
}
```

Check this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402278/serving-precompiled-assets-with-nginx)

Comment: Nothing, I still get the same 404 error. Restarted everything and nothing. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't work either. Have you successfully deployed a Rails+Nginx+Passenger application before? If so, how did you do it? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I did. Can you pastebin your nginx config?

Comment: Check this out: https://gist.github.com/1844834
Note: You have to execute rake assets:precompile since it's in production environment.

Comment: Sure, here it is https://gist.github.com/a9c44d347b265e298fc9
I'm trying yours too.

Comment: Don't forget the "rake assets:precompile" if you're in production environment

Comment: Yes, I did the "rake assets:precompile" part before and it worked, but I don't expect that for every deploy I have to run that command over and over, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have to do it for every deploy.

Comment: Do you know if I can get Capistrano to do that for me?

Comment: Yes, It can.

Check this: https://moocode.com/posts/1-deploying-a-rails-3-1-application-to-production