# Nginx hosting a single Rails app on sub uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

Background:

- I am running a debian 7 server behind a reverse proxy.
- I have a rails 4 app running ruby 2.0.0-p247
- I am using nginx
- Server is accessed by navigating to: server-name.foo.dev where foo.dev is the internal reverse proxy domain.
- I am unable to use passenger to deploy the app.
- This will be the only app running on the server.

Problem:

I need to host the rails app on a sub uri or context root path on the server behind the reverse proxy, so that when users navigate to the website, the url for the root path looks like this:

- server-name.foo.dev/rails_app, where rails_app would be the root of the rails app.

How would I set this up in nginx sites-enabled config file, and is there anything I would have to modify on the rails app to allow it to sever the correct paths to static content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use Unicorn instead of Passenger. 
You can set up both of them(Unicorn and Nginx) as reverse proxy.
[This link](http://sirupsen.com/setting-up-unicorn-with-nginx/) will be pretty good paper for you..

Again, you 'rewrite'(Nginx route feature) /rails_app to rails application's Unicorn socket file(usually using upstream).

See also below code snippets.

partial nginx.conf

```
location ~* ^/(rails_app)/ {
  root   /your/rails/home;
  index  index.html index.htm;
  proxy_pass http://socket_proxy_name;
}
```

partial snippet for proxy_pass

```
upstream socket_proxy_name{
  server unix:/your/socket/paht.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Comment: I got this working serving my application under localhost/claxon, where claxon is my apps root. Now, how would I configure either nginx or my rails app to serve the static assets and stylesheets/js/etc? It is still looking at localhost/assets... for the rails assets.

Comment: Serving your static assets with rails process is bad idea. Nginx is serving your static resources extremely faster than rails. "how can i serving rails application's assets?"'s answer is easy to find. this link will be helpful to you. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402278/serving-precompiled-assets-with-nginx". cheers:)

Comment: I should rephrase my question: When I navigate to localhost/claxon, it is serving the html, but without styling, as it is still looking for styling at localhost/assets/... How do I get rails to look for its assets at localhost/claxon/assets?

Comment: Okay. Try "config.assets.prefix = "claxon/assets"" at your 'config/application.rb' configuration file.

Comment: Could this also be placed in the production.rb if I only wanted it in the production environment?

Comment: Im not sure. Just try it. If that is impossible, why don't you write in application.rb with Rails.env conditional statement?:)