# Rails production routes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, routes, passenger

In production I get the following in the log:

> I, [2013-11-28T10:37:59.495396 #1181]  INFO -- : Started GET
>   "/javascripts/application.js" for 91.104.133.126 at 2013-11-28
>   10:37:59 +0000 F, [2013-11-28T10:37:59.497931 #1181] FATAL -- : 
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/javascripts/application.js"):

And:

> I, [2013-11-28T10:41:05.611348 #1181]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for
>   91.104.133.126 at 2013-11-28 10:41:05 +0000 I, [2013-11-28T10:41:05.615742 #1181]  INFO -- : Processing by
>   PagesController#home as HTML I, [2013-11-28T10:41:05.626276 #1181] 
>   INFO -- :   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
>   (7.5ms) I, [2013-11-28T10:41:05.629343 #1181]  INFO -- : Completed 200
>   OK in 13ms (Views: 10.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms) I,
>   [2013-11-28T10:41:05.817024 #1181]  INFO -- : Started GET
>   "/stylesheets/application.css" for 91.104.133.126 at 2013-11-28
>   10:41:05 +0000 F, [2013-11-28T10:41:05.819748 #1181] FATAL -- : 
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/stylesheets/application.css"):

This didn't happen during development.

App is runnig with RVM & NginX & Passenger, all latest version, fresh install.

**Update 1:**

After running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I get these:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/assets/application-0292b59e3ea25ff21b6f72e062924c42.css"):
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/javascripts/vendor/modernizr.js"):
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/assets/application-2f1ac76c2ad0b69f7bbab4b9d9dca4b8.js"):

**Update 2:**

Output of `rake routes`

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
              images_new GET    /images/new(.:format)      images#new
           users_sign_up GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)   users#sign_up
             images_edit GET    /images/edit(.:format)     images#edit
            images_index GET    /images/index(.:format)    images#index
             images_show GET    /images/show(.:format)     images#show
               posts_new GET    /posts/new(.:format)       posts#new
              posts_edit GET    /posts/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
            posts_update GET    /posts/update(.:format)    posts#update
           posts_destroy GET    /posts/destroy(.:format)   posts#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)   devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)   devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)  devise/sessions#destroy  cancel_user_registration GET /users/cancel(.:format)    devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)           devise/registrations#create     new_user_registration GET

/users/sign_up(.:format)   devise/registrations#new   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)      devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)           devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)           devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)           devise/registrations#destroy
              pages_home GET    /pages/home(.:format)      pages#home
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)           posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)           posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)       posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)  posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#destroy
                  images GET    /images(.:format)          images#index
                         POST   /images(.:format)          images#create
               new_image GET    /images/new(.:format)      images#new
              edit_image GET    /images/:id/edit(.:format) images#edit
                   image GET    /images/:id(.:format)      images#show
                         PATCH  /images/:id(.:format)      images#update
                         PUT    /images/:id(.:format)      images#update
                         DELETE /images/:id(.:format)      images#destroy
                    root GET    /                          pages#home
```

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: When I try to run it, i get this: rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter

Comment: Ok, what about `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: This one goes through without error, but still get the same log messages.

Comment: Are you using asset_url('path_to_asset') in your views?

Comment: No I am using the following: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

Comment: Which directory did you run '... assets:precompile' in?
Make sure it is /var/www/webroot/ROOT (and not /var/ftp/webroot/ROOT)

Answer (score 3):

try set `config.assets.compile = true` in produciton.rb

Comment: Note that this might be a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` in production.rb

Comment: Though this 'fixes' the issue, this is not advised in a production environment. This will cause static assets to be served by the Rails app which is often times slower than serving via a server like Nginx. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402278/serving-precompiled-assets-with-nginx